# Using WATIR, how do you press the "Bid Now" button on Quibids.com

Tags: watir

I'm using Watir to try to interface to the Quibids "Bid Now" (not Buy Now) button but can't seem to get the right combination of the following command to click the button:

```
browser.button(:value => 'Bid Now').click
```

I'm able to fill in a text field on the page so all my object set up is correct.  It's just this command that I can't get to work.   Every attempt gives me the error that the element cannot be found.  I've also tried :id but nothing works and after working on it for 2 hours, thought I'd ask.

The following is the html out of IE around that button and any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<p class="large-price">
    <span style="background-image: none;" class="price">$5.68</span>
    <span class="medium light-grey">USD</span>
</p>        

<p class="time large-timer2 red">00:00:06</p>

<h2 class="margin-five username-height">
    <span><img style="display: inline;" class="user-icon winning_avatar" src="https://s1.quibidscdn.com/n1/avatards/12.png" width="64" height="64"></span>
    <br>
    <span style="height: 30px;" class="winning">TOLLCOLLECTOR</span>
</h2>

<div id="298085604">
    <p>
        <a class="buttons bid large orange" href="#">Bid Now</a>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    AuctionDetail.updateSavings({"r":0,"v":0,"value":0});
});
</script>

<ul class="price-breakdown">
    <li>Value Price: 
        <span id="product_valueprice" class="float-right">$649.99</span>
    </li>

    <li>Bids Credit:
        <span class="float-right">- <span id="breakdown_bidsvalue">$0.00</span></span>
    </li>

    <li class="bid_breakdown last">
        <span id="breakdown_realbids">0</span> Real / <span id="breakdown_voucherbids">0</span> Voucher                         </li>   

    <li>Buy Now Price<span class="float-right breakdown_buynowtotal">$649.99</span>
    </li>
</ul>


<p>
<a id="buynowbtn" class="buynowbtn buttons large blue" href="#">
    Buy Now 
    <span class="clear"></span> 
    <span class="buynow-price breakdown_buynowbtn">$649.99</span>
</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML does not list it as a button. It lists it as a link- `<a>`. I've never used WATIR but given that the command is `browser.button`, it would seem that you need something like `browser.link` instead.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you for your help!  The correct code was:

b.link(:text, "Bid Now").click

Answer (score 0):

The process is quicker if you don't do a text scan and use the classes available to you:

I'd recommend using

```
 browser.a(:class => "buttons bid large orange").click
```

instead, both will work, just generally it would be better practice to use the html if it's available to you!

Answer (score 0):

My Friend...

My two possibilities.

```
browser.div(:id, "298085604").text(:name "Bid Now").click
```

or

```
browser.div(:text, "Bid Now").click
```

Remember that, the HTML is not displayed all functions, only the HTML code that the browser recognizes. this is the cause of programming language. example (framework, NET) these encrypted language code for the final user. You can not see the button entirely.

Good Luck!

Comment: Note that an answer was already found by DeadMG. The element was a link not a button.